# Pre-populating a BooleanField as checked (WTForms)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to pre-populate a BooleanField with WTForms.  I have a field called "active".  It defaults to being not checked, and it's not required.  So I set it up like...

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    question = TextField('Question', [validators.Required()])
    slug = TextField('Slug', [validators.Required()])
    active = BooleanField('Active')
```

Then I have an EDIT PAGE where I display a form for the 'question' I want to edit.

```
{{ form.question.label }}
{{ form.question(value=q.question) }}

{{ form.active(value=q.active) }} Show this question?
```

If 'active' is True, I'd like the BooleanField (checkbox) to have the 'checked' attribute.  And if False, not to.  But I can't even figure out how to make the checkbox have a checked state, when rendering the form, let alone the conditional part.

The only way, I've been able to get it to show up checked is if I add default=True when defining the form.  But that's not what I need.

I've tried using 'default', 'initial', 'value', 'selected' while rendering the form with no luck.  And I've searched the docs and Google.  I think I'm missing something! :)

UPDATE

Here's what my view looks like.  Maybe it is the problem?

```
@mod.route('/q/<slug>/edit', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(slug):
    form = QuestionForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    q = Question.query(Question.slug==slug).get()
    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            q.question = form.data.get('question')
            q.slug = form.data.get('slug')
            q.active = form.data.get('active')
            q.put()
            return redirect('/questions')
    return render_template('questions/edit.html', form=form, q=q)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have an object you can use it to populate your form like `form = QuestionForm(obj=my_obj)`. If you only want to set the active attribute use `form = QuestionForm(active=True)`.

Comment: I added my view to the question.  I think I'm doing it right.  Or do I need to use the 'q' object when defining my form?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, use your `q` object. `form = QuestionForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False, obj=q)`

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  It all makes sense now!  You're a genius!

Comment: This worked for me, but only when I removed the other bits; `form = QuestionForm(formdata=request.form, obj=result)` didn't fill the checkbox properly, but `QuestionForm(obj=result)` did!

Comment: The proposed solution worked for me: `QuestionForm(active=True)`. In my case the solution did not work as I was passing variables and the variable was of type string instead of bool, causing this solution to not work. Cast the variable to bool first and then this solution works as a charm.

Answer (score 12):

A BooleanField defined like:

```
checkbox = BooleanField('title',
              default=True,
              render_kw ={'checked':''})
```

Comment: Both `default=True` and `default="checked"` worked for me. I didn't need the render_kw part, can you elaborate why that would be necessary?

Comment: Hello, as far as I remember I have added the Checkbox label for the checkbox to be selected.`<input **checked** type="checkbox">`

Comment: only the `render_kw={"checked": ...}` worked here, didn't even need the `default` part

Answer (score 7):

snahor's answer helped after much searching (+1). The google seems weak on this question. I found I needed

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{adminForm.is_admin.label}}
  {{adminForm.is_admin(checked=True, class_="form-control")}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{adminForm.is_admin.label}}
  {{adminForm.is_admin(checked=False, class_="form-control")}}
</div>
```

which I have utilised as

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{adminForm.is_admin.label}}
  {{adminForm.is_admin(checked=user.is_admin, class_="form-control")}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is only thing that worked for me with Flask 0.12 and WTForms 2.1

Comment: "The google seems weak on this question."

Yes, b/c the web it broken.

Answer (score 2):

To have the default boolean value as True, you need to set the default to "checked"

> Basic fields Basic fields generally represent scalar data types with
>   single values, and refer to a single input from the form.
>
> ```
> class wtforms.fields.BooleanField(default field arguments, false_values=None)
> ```
>
> Represents an input type="checkbox". Set the
>   checked-status by using the default-option. Any value for default,
>   e.g. default="checked" puts checked into the html-element and sets the
>   data to True

[Source](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.BooleanField)

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    question = TextField('Question', [validators.Required()])
    slug = TextField('Slug', [validators.Required()])
    active = BooleanField('Active', default="checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. There seems to be a [bug in WTForms that has not been fixed](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/362).

Instead, when the route is called I set the value of the Boolean field after I have initialised the form. This works for me

```
form = GameCreateForm(request.form)
form.allow_comments.data = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after hours of searching and reading, the solution was very simple.

```
form = forms.TestForm(request.form)
form.yourbooleanfield.checked = YourVariable

if request.method=="POST" and form.validate():
    print(form.yourbooleanfield.data)
```

Comment: Uhh I don't think that's a great solution. I mean you could put the setting of checked AFTER your if statement up there. Because if you don't do that it'll always be set to YourVariable and it won't matter what the user put in...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying in the template, you can likewise specify in the class definition

```
class QuestionForm(Form):
    question        = TextField('Question', [validators.Required()])
    slug            = TextField('Slug'    , [validators.Required()])
    activeChecked   = BooleanField('Active', default=True  )
    activeUnChecked = BooleanField('Active', default=False )
```

Comment: Has no effect for me. Always defaults to false

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```py
BooleanField(default="checked")
```

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/

```py
class wtforms.fields.BooleanField(default field arguments, false_values=None)
```