# Can a WTForms BooleanField have a custom value?

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I would like to use WTForms (actually Flask-WTF) to generate this:

```
<input id="attr" name="attr" type="checkbox" value="ALL"> Include all attributes
```

but if there is any way to specify a value as part of BooleanField, I cannot find it.  If I specify:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    attr = BooleanField('attr', default=False, description="Include all attributes")
```

and render it in the template:

```
{{ form.attr }} {{ form.attr.description }}
```

then I get

```
<input id="attr" name="attr" type="checkbox" value="y"> Include all attributes
```

BooleanField doesn't have a "choices" or "value" property to set.  Is there any way to force it to have a value of my choosing (e.g. `ALL`) instead of just `y` ?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758112/pre-populating-a-booleanfield-as-checked-wtforms

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to be a discussion on how to conditionally make a checkbox active (checked) when rendering a form, not how to customize its "value" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Booleanfield` can only have value attribute set to True or False.

`SelectField` or `RadioField` can be used to setup checkboxes with custom value.

```
class TestForm(Form): 
    Attr_field = SelectField("Attr ", choices=[("ALL", "label")], default="ALL")
```

Use `SelectMultipleField` to setup a list of checkboxes and populate them all.